# Need to terminate program using "enter" key

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> var;
int numb;
cout<<"Enter numbers: ";
//While loop for inputting integers with space and pushing it to vector
while(cin>>numb){
        var.push_back(numb);}
insertionSort(var);
for(int a=0;a<var.size();a++){
    cout<<var[a]<<" ";
}
```

How can I terminate the while loop using "enter key" without using Ctrl+Z?

Answer (score 1):

`peek` looks at the next character without pulling it out of the buffer. `'\n'` is the newline character for the compilation target character set and encoding. So, this code allows:

1. No numbers to be entered, ending with  <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. One or more numbers to be entered, ending with  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

.

```
while (cin.peek() != '\n' && cin >> numb) {
    var.push_back(numb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to use EOF, e.g. send Ctrl-D from keyboard should work for cin. You do not need enter key. But of course, you could use getline() instead, and terminate on an empty line.

Comment: Our prof said that the program should only be terminated with the enter key. Is there any solution for this? Without using Ctrl-D or Z?

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool called running, set it to true. Change the condition of your while loop to be

```
while (yourcondition && running == true)
```

And inside your while loop, check if the input is the enter key (it will have an ASCII value, look it up, it might be 13). Set this running bool to false when the enter key is input to your program.

```
if (input == enter)
    running = false;
```

This would cause the next iteration of your while loop to fail, and continue on with the rest of your program, where you could exit with return 0;, for example.

Comment: No, no, no! No need the running to compare with true :)))

Comment: @AlexanderChernin I agree. I've finally figured out that people do this to improve readability. To which, I would say, then rename the variable to something more conversational like `isRunning`, `haveNotQuitYet` or whatever. (Oh, and in some languages it does matter but is often a bug to use ` == true`.)